# How to Display data in bar chart as per the below image

Tags: asp.net

[image]

How to display like the above image on the day by day and hours  basis on bar Charts

Comment: Did you try anything so far, if so please post where you experience problem. If nothing yet, did you take a look at [.NET provided Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632.aspx) controls?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link for Google Combo Chart example with database in ASP.NET

http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/google-combo-chart-example-with-database-in-Asp-Net-1099.aspx